# How do I convert every element in an array to its own array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings ...

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

How do I take the above and convert each element into its own array of one element?  So I would want the result of such an operation to be

```
[["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```

?

Comment: `["a", "b", "c"].each_cons(1).to_av#=> [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]` is yet another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
["a", "b", "c"].zip #=> [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was previously iterating over each id passing to a Sidekiq job. I saw the api for `perform_bulk` and needed to get each id into its own array.

Comment: @aaronkelton that's nice to know this answer has helped in an actual practical situation; the Ruby language is great!

Answer (score 2):

```
a.map { |s| Array(s) }
```

or

```
a.map { |s| [s] }
```

Comment: `["a", "b", "c"].map &Kernel.method(:Array)`

Comment: @mudasobwa Or since `Kernel` is mixed into everything so that we can pretend to have functions: `["a", "b", "c"].map &method(:Array)`

Comment: Unexciting, but 99% of Rubiests would elect your #2.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) or [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) methods, it also provide little bit more functionality

```
a.combination(1).to_a
#=> [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
a.combination(2).to_a
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]     

a.permutation(1).to_a
#=> [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
a.permutation(2).to_a
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that you can use `Array#zip` to do this. I did not realize `#zip` worked at all without an argument. Ruby always has a new trick up its sleeve.

Not that this is any better, but it might be a bit more intuitive:

```
>> ["a", "b", "c"].each_slice(1).to_a
=> [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```